# SetParent to hook, how do you unhook?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, release

How would you unhook an application from your form once it's now using it as the parent?

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

SetParent(setter, this.panel1.Handle);
```

to unhook i tried SetParent(setter, setter);  with no luck.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that, but i'd try to set the old parent (whatever that was), by storing it before setting the new one.

Comment: Umm sorry I cant understand `unhook an application from your form` - what does this mean? Like when you drag a Chrome tab into its own App? Please elaborate :)

Comment: [msdn docs on SetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541(v=vs.85).aspx) say that setting parent to NULL hooks it to desktop. Don't have any experience with that, though

Comment: exception, intptr to null not possible, no result from (IntPtr)null

Comment: @ploxtic try to use `IntPtr.Zero` instead of .Net `null`.

Comment: still a no go..hooked right in still

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but I was able to pass in zero to unhook from the parent:

```
SetParent(process.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero);
```

This will set the desktop window as the new parent.

Answer (score 0):

SetParent returns the previous parent window handle. To "unhook" the window you should be able to call SetParent with the handle you originally got back.

Comment: nope. unless you have to move the window via your program also, this does not work.. stuck inside the form/panel

Comment: If the previous owner was the desktop I'm not sure there would be any obvious visual effect from restoring the parent unless you move one of the participating windows, or something.

Comment: Chrome, Notepad: both don't bounce back outside of the form/panel with IntPtr.Zero or -1, null, or its own handle. Did it work for you?  Or which handle are you considering "originally got back."